# implementing both session, cookie in a login form

Tags: php, session

i'm implementing session, cookie simple from with a remember me check box . i want to use the cookie so the user could see index.php(protected content)  i closed the browser to end the session to check if the cookie working and i got the famous error ..redirected you too many  . i searched a bit   but still stuck so what should i do? and Is what is the best practice to for doing it?

**authentication.php**

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($rows) > 0){

       $chck_pass = password_verify($clean_password,$user_arr["password"]);

      if($chck_pass){

            //log in the user
            $_SESSION["id"] =$user_arr["id"];
            $_SESSION["fristname"] = $user_arr["fristname"];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $user_arr["email"];
            $_SESSION["verified"]=$user_arr["verified"];
            $_SESSION["message"]="Please verify Your Email to Complete Registration";

            //make login-id cookie
            if(isset($_POST["remmberme"])){

              $user=$user_arr['id'];
              setcookie("I_user",$user, time() + 1800);
               }


            header("location:index.php");
            exit();

          }else{
            $errors["login_error"]="Wrong Password";}


      }else{
        $errors["login_error"]="Wrong Email";
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php 
include("Authentication.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION["id"]) || !isset($_COOKIE['I_user']) ){


    header("location:login.php");
}


 ?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

require_once("config/db_connect.php");
require("Authentication.php");

if(isset($_COOKIE['I_user'])|| isset( $_SESSION['id'])){


  header("location:index.php");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you login, close your browser. Then open it up again.

You go to index.php and the following line runs

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["id"]) || !isset($_COOKIE['I_user']) ){
```

`$_SESSION["id"]` **isn't set**, so you redirect to login.php.

On login.php

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['I_user'])|| isset( $_SESSION['id'])){
```

`$_COOKIE['I_user']` **is set**, so you redirect to index.php

Repeat forever.